# How to use gulp-bless with gulp-useref

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-useref

I would use the gulp-bless plugin to separate bower CSS files, because the generated minified file is too long and isn't processed completely in IE 9.

But the file generated by gulp-bless plugin isn't replaced in the "index.html" file by gulp-useref plugin.

The gulp useref plugin also can't join all files, would keep the structure generated by the gulp-bless plugin.

File "index.html" (css imports and useref)
[image: css useref parts]

File "gulpfile.js" (part of build task)
[image: Filter for css files]
[image: part of build task]

File "index.html" (dist)
[image: Generated index.html file]

Generated dist files
[image: Generated dist files]

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the sourceMap.